# Printing an array statement

Tags: java, arrays, words

When I try to print myWords in a separate class, all I get a a blank statement. I'm pretty sure the code is right but I just can't get it to print the words that I want. Please help!

```
public String[] multiLetter (int n, char included)
//public String[] multiLetter(int n, char included)
//returns an array of words with at least m occurrences
//of the letter included

{   
    for (int i = 0 ; i < words.size() ; i++)    
    {
        int repeatCounter = 0;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < words.get(i).length(); j ++)
        {   
            if (included == words.get(i).charAt(j))
            {
                repeatCounter ++;
            }
        }//closes inner for loop 

        if (repeatCounter >= n)
        {
            myWords.add(words.get(i));
        }
    }

    String [] array = new String [myWords.size()];
    return myWords.toArray(array);              
}
```

Comment: You never print anything.

Comment: You have left out enough of the relevant info that we can't help you.

Comment: We need to see the class where you attempt to print the array

Comment: How is myWords defined? You can add as first line of method the following code: `List<String> myWords = new ArrayList<String>();`. It is enough when myWords is local variable.

Answer (score 1):

First: using the way you coded, you have to receive a list of String as a paramater.
Second: you have to create you `myWords` variable.
I think your code should be ok that way:

```
public String[] multiLetter (int n, char included, List<String> words)
//public String[] multiLetter(int n, char included)
//returns an array of words with at least m occurrences
//of the letter included
{   
    List<String> myWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < words.size() ; i++)    
    {
        int repeatCounter = 0;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < words.get(i).length(); j ++)
        {   
            if (included == words.get(i).charAt(j))
            {
                repeatCounter++;
            }
        }//closes inner for loop 

        if (repeatCounter >= n)
        {
            myWords.add(words.get(i));
        }
    }
    return (String[])myWords.toArray();             
}
```